# Is there a way to do a two-way Indicator Species Analysis?

Tags: r, statistics, spatial

I'm trying to run an indicator species analysis after doing an nmds using this function "multipatt" and I followed the steps on this website: https://jkzorz.github.io/2019/07/02/Indicator-species-analysis.html

I want to know what fungal taxa's are being consumed by each species, and during what seasons.

But I noticed you can only have one treatment group. For my problem, I have taxa information and I have "two treatments", one is species and one is season.

My code is set up like this:

```
Sq_rt_indic <- multipatt(Taxa.sq.clean, seasontype, func = "r.g", control = how(nperm=9999))
```

Where "Taxa.sq.clean" is my taxa data. "Seasontype" is the season information. But I want to add another treatment. How can I include "seasontype" AND "speciestype"? Simply putting a "+" or interaction "*" doesnt work.

Attached are screenshots on what the 3 datas look like. Note - season and species are both factors, but I can make them into dfs.

[image]

[image]

I could parse out species and season but I just want both of them accounted for in the model.

Comment: I don't know anything about that package or that function, but presumably you could create a variable that combines both the season and species levels into a factor variable with 6 levels, and then use that in `multipatt()`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.